# What's the best way to connect these two Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a Django project I have a Companies model and am putting together a ClinicalTrials model (CT), both of which are stored in a SQlite3 database for now.  My initial plan was to query the CT.gov API for a company_name when a user visits the company page and store the results in the CT model mapping the company's primary key from the Companies model to a Foreign Key in the CT model.

As I start working through it though, I've realized that a trial will have a lead and could have multiple Collaborators which would result in storing multiple copies of the same trial record.  So, I want to write the trial record once once and then connect multiple companies to the record.

My problem arises when I try to connect the other companies to the trial, simple because the company names in the trail are not always an exact match in my Companies model (i.e. my Companies table has the company_name as "Pharma Company Inc." and the collaborator field is "Pharma Company").

Is it best to search the Companies model using regex?  Is there a better solution?

Also, what's the best way to store multiple Foreign Keys in a model?  Or is better to build a helper table?  Not really sure here...

**Update**
Adding code for clarity

ClinicalTrial model in my clincialtrial App

```
class ClinicalTrials(models.Model):
    pk = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    involvement = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    current_trial_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    current_trial_status_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    start_date_type_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    completion_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    completion_date_type_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    record_verification_date = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    brief_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    official_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    brief_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    study_protocol_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    primary_purpose_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    lead_org = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    minimum_target_accrual_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    number_of_arms = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Company model in my dashboard App

```
class Company(models.Model):
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=False)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
```

Comment: It is a lot hard to understand when you explain your models just in english. Should be more helpful if you can post the relevant part of your models. Anyway, from what I understood, you need to create a ManyToMany relationship between the models instead of ForeignKey.

Comment: I haven't used the ManyToMany relationship before but that seems like that right way to connect them.  Just need to figure out how to look up company names that don't exactly match...

Comment: I guess you haven't yet added the `collaborator` field you've mentioned in your question. Changing the `lead_org` field to a ForeignKey and adding `collaborator` field as a ManyToMany relationship to `Company` model should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the relevant part of your ClinicalTrials Model here:

```
class ClinicalTrials(models.Model):
    ...
    lead_org = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    ...
    collaborator = Models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    ...
```

Then if you want to fetch all the `ClinicalTrial` objects that "Pharma Company Inc." is lead of, you just have to write the below filter

```
ClinicalTrials.objects.filter(lead_org__name="Pharma Company Inc.")
```

And if you want to fetch all the `ClinicalTrial` objects that "Pharma Company Inc." is a collaborator of, you can write:

```
ClinicalTrials.objects.filter(collaborator__name="Pharma Company Inc.")
```